# Does EHCache 3.x support replicated caching using JGroups?

Tags: ehcache

Have query regarding EHCache and Jgroups. We have been using EHCache 2.9 with replicated caching using Jgroups. However in the latest 3.x version, I don't see any reference to replicated caching using Jgroups. Is this no longer supported in 3.x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's no longer supported.
If you want to use a clustered caching tier, [you can use the open source Terracotta server](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.1/clustered-cache.html)